# A value that is no longer borrowed causes a "does not live long enough" error

Tags: rust

This program cannot be compiled.

```rust
struct F<'a>(Box<dyn Fn() + 'a>);

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![]; // Vec<F>
    let s = String::from("foo");

    let f = F(Box::new(|| println!("{:?}", s)));
    v.push(f);

    drop(v);
}
```

```
error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:7:44
   |
7  |     let f = F(Box::new(|| println!("{:?}", s)));
   |                        --                  ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                        |
   |                        value captured here
...
11 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `s` dropped here while still borrowed
   | borrow might be used here, when `v` is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `Vec`
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are defined
```

When `s` is dropped(line 11), `v` is already dropped, so `s` is not borrowed.
But the compiler said that `s` was still borrowed. why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the consideration that a panic could happen as a result of any function call, since there is no decoration on functions indicating whether they might panic.

When a panic occurs, the stack unwinds and the drop code for each (initialized) variable is run in the opposite of their declaration order (`s` is dropped first, and then `v`)  But `v` has the type `Vec<F<'a>>` where `'a` is the lifetime of `s`, and `F` implements `Drop`, which means that `s` cannot be dropped before `v` because the compiler can't guarantee that the drop code for `F` won't access `s`.

The compiler cannot tell that there isn't actually a memory safety issue here (if `push` panics, the vector doesn't reference `s` through the closure).  All it knows is that **the type of `v` must live at least as long as `s`**; whether `v` actually contains a reference to `s` is immaterial.

To fix this, just swap the order `v` and `s` are declared in, which will guarantee that `v` is dropped before `s`.

---

But why does `F` implement `Drop` in the first place?

Note that the problem goes away if you remove the `Fn()` trait object and push the closure directly (e.g. without `dyn`).  This case is different because the compiler *knows* that the closure doesn't implement `Drop` -- the closure didn't move-capture any values that implement `Drop`.  Therefore, the compiler knows that `s` will not be accessed by `v`'s drop code.

By comparison, trait objects *always* have a vtable slot for `Drop::drop`, and so the compiler must pessimistically assume that every trait object could have a `Drop` implementation.  This means that when the `Vec` and `Box` are destroyed, the compiler emits code to call the trait object's drop code, and based on the information the compiler has, that *can* result in an access to `s` since the `F` value captures the lifetime of `s`.

This is one of the pitfalls about type erasure through trait objects: the trait object is opaque to the compiler and it can no longer verify that `s` won't be used by a `Drop` implementation of a boxed closure after `s` is dropped.  If an owned trait object captures a lifetime, the compiler has to ensure that the captured lifetime does not end before the trait object is dropped.

---

The above is actually a somewhat simplified explanation.  Rust's [drop-checker](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/dropck.html) is a bit more complex than this; it's okay if `F` *auto-implements* `Drop` so long as the drop-checker determines that the lifetime `'a` doesn't get used.  Because of the trait object, this can't be guaranteed.  However, this code *can* compile with a `Box` holding a non-`dyn` closure as the drop-checker determines that the captured lifetime isn't used when dropping the box.

Comment: the problem goes away if you remove the `Fn()` trait and push the closure directly... could you please elaborate a bit on this implementation a bit more? I couldn't get to a working example.

Comment: @AshishSingh [For example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=11f6022d83021eaa662349a86a7cd77e)